# export all settings of Office 365 with powershell

Tags: office365, azure-powershell

I found lots of resources how to manage content on O365 with powershell,  but not much regarding to manage the settings. For audit reasons, we need to check time to time that all the settings within O365 are correct and according to company policy. 
 This goes over literally all options in all admin console (Sharepoint, OneDrive etc) and listing its value in a report like:

> module, option, value 
>  sharepoint, external sharing, disabled

Is there a simple way to walk trough these options with powershell (or another tool) and get their value? I mean, without calling them one by one as I would like to avoid editing the code every time a new feature is coming to O365.

edit:
I finally found this:

```
Get-SPOTenant | fl
```

This list, I think, all or most of the Sharepoint Online settings, are there such tenant-level functions for other services?

Comment: I'd be happy if I could have this one line for each service :)

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot get all services settings in O365 from one command.

Comment: That is clear, but can I get them by service? Is there an overview of tenant or service level powershell cmdlets?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Office365DSC to export all configuration settings:
https://github.com/microsoft/Office365DSC/wiki/What-is-Office365DSC

It automatically extracts all configuration settings as a PowerShell Desired State Configuration script.